# can I change the iphone 5S text tone swoosh on sending to a more noticable sound

Tags: iphone

can I change the text tone swoosh on sending to something louder/more noticable on my iphone 5S, if so how? Thanks

Comment: Try going to Settings -> Sound and changing the "sent mail" sound. I'm not positive this will work but it's the best idea I have right now

Answer (score -2):

See the Settings.
Sounds: see under "Sounds and Vibration Patterns".
Self explanatory.

Comment: Which of the lines there relates to the sound played when sending a *text* message? It may be self explanatory to you, but others (including myself) may not know which option there relates to text sending.